# Orion Context Broker DBQuery

Tags: fiware, fiware-orion

How to solve the problem with the configuration of MongoDB and Orion, in order to increase the number of DBQuery.shellBatchSize? 
For inquiries type regex (e.g.  " Room.* ") Orion Broker returned just 20 hits, but there are over 1000

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer, **Pagination**

```
POST <orion_host>:1026/v1/queryContext?limit=100&details=on
```